# How to use VS to arrange classes from left to right?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, class-diagram

**Questions.**

1. How to use VS to arrange classes from left to right?
2. Is it possible to arrange classes from left to right using VS?

I am using a project for review
https://github.com/jhon65496/Northwind_Q
VS has built a class diagram.
I want to: expand the classes and make them arranged from left to right.

**Pic-1**
[image]

**Pic-2**
[image]

**Pic-3**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the arrangement in Solution Explorer to be left to right it seems impossible. Visual Studio has not enabled this feature.

But if you want each class file to be arranged in Tabs from left to right, this is possible, you just need to follow the steps below:

Tools => Options => Environment => Tabs and Windows => Check "Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs"

[image]

The effect is as follows:

[image]